# How to change the shape of Points from ThreeJS from a square into a circle?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am using React, Three JS, React-Three-Fibre

Here is what I have:

```
// Texture for Points
    const getTexture = (size, color) => {
        const matCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        matCanvas.width = matCanvas.height = size;
        const matContext = matCanvas.getContext('2d');
        const texture = new THREE.Texture(matCanvas);

        const center = size / 2;
        matContext.beginPath();
        matContext.arc(center, center, size/2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        matContext.closePath();
        matContext.fillStyle = color;
        matContext.fill();

        //texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        return texture;
    }

    const vertices = [];

    for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {

        const x = THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread( 10 );
        const y = THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread( 10 );
        const z = THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread( 10 );

        vertices.push( x, y, z );

    }

    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );

    const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color: 0x123684 } );
    const points = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
```

And here is the R3F

```
return (
        <points args={[geometry]}>
            <pointsMaterial
                size={1}
                map={getTexture(10, 'red')}
            />
        </points>
    )
```

The problem is instead of the points changing shape from square to circle, instead they are the picture of a circle inside of a square

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPcvw.png)